# Symbols for Shevet Levi and the Kohanim

Tags: sources-mekorot, kohen-priest, symbols-symbology, levites-leviyim

Usually, I've seen hands in the position of [nesiyat](http://www.myjewishlearning.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/02/priestly-blessing-kohen-gravestone.jpg) [kapayim](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Priestly_Blessing) to represent Kohanim and a [laver](http://www.studiolum.com/wang/polish/lesko/lesko-jewish-cemetery-003.jpg) to represent other members of Shevet Levi. These are fairly common imagery.

My question is whether Chazal or the Rishonim discuss visual symbols which would serve as a shorthand for Leviyim and Kohanim, as Levi is the only tribe without a banner described in the Torah (Bamidbar 10). If so, where are they found and what are they?

Comment: Hmm, what makes you think Chazal would discuss visual symbols for Leviim and Kohanim? It was my impression that these symbols generally are found on gravestones - and definitely not gravestones from Zman Chazal. Where else would these symbols come up?

Comment: @ezra, I didn't write up a complex question, because I was using my iPhone, however every other shevet has an insignia on its flag (see Bamidbar 10 in Beha'alotcha). I figure that Chaza"l or the Rishonim would fill in the blanks, even if only unofficially.